# Why is tkinter not recognizing that this window is being resized?

Tags: python, python-2.7, window, tkinter

When I try to detect that a window is resized with tkinter, it works most of the time. However, there is one exception; that is, when resizing it for the first time vertically and making the window larger, nothing is picked up. I see the initial size when the window appears, but nothing after that if I try to immediately make the window larger vertically. However, if I try to make it vertically "taller," after resizing it another way (ie making it smaller or resizing horizontally), then it works fine.

Here's the gist of the code I'm using:

```
from Tkinter import *
main = Tk()
def resize(event):
    print("The new dimensions are:",event.width,"x",event.height)
    window.focus_set()
canvas = Canvas(main, width=850, height=400)
window = Frame(main, width=800, height=10)
window.focus_set()
canvas.bind("<Configure>", resize)
canvas.pack()
canvas.update()
window.pack()
main.mainloop()
```

Am I doing something wrong?
If it matters, I'm using Python 2.7.3 on 64 bit Ubuntu 12.10

**EDIT:** It seems as though the dimensions are either incorrect (horizontal enlargement) or not showing up at all (vertical enlargement) when the window size is above `852x402`. Is this a problem with my window manager (ie, Unity)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `canvas = Canvas(main, width=850, height=400)` by `canvas = Canvas(main, width=850, height=400, bg="red")` and see what happens.

Since the canvas is inside the root window, when you make the window vertically larger, you are not changing the canvas size or position. It maintains its maximum height of 400, and the handler is not called. However, in the case of the horizontal enlargement, its position is exactly the middle because of the call to `pack()`: That's why it moves, and the bound function is called.

The rest of the results when you make the window smaller both horizontally and vertically are as expected.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying why horizontal resize works and vertical doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the canvas is *not* being resized. You're setting the binding on the canvas, but you haven't configured the canvas to grow and shrink along with the containing window.

Try setting the background of the canvas and frame widgets to something distinctive and you'll see what I mean.

To fix the problem try setting the `expand` and `fill` attributes when packing your widgets.

Comment: When I use try the pack parameters as (fill=BOTH, expand=YES), the canvas is not filling the window vertically. Why's that? I removed the height and width parameters for the canvas.

Comment: @Vreality: I find that hard to believe. Are you saying with the _exact_ code in your question, but with that one change only to where you pack the canvas, the canvas doesn't resize?

Comment: No. It resizes, but not fully vertically. (There's a little grey space at the bottom of the window).

Comment: @Vreality: that is no doubt due to a borderwidth, highlightthickness, or padding setting.

Comment: Those are all set to 0 by default and I haven't added them. The same is true with my example code; if you add the fill and expand attributes and change the color of the canvas or window,  you can see that there's a little space at the bottom. (see http://screencloud.net/v/x0SA)

Comment: It also increases if you make the window taller.

Comment: @Vreality: there must be something you're not telling me. If I change nothing but the one line to be `canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)`, the canvas fills in both directions as I grow and shrink the window, as I would expect.

Comment: @Vreality: as for the space at the bottom -- you're probably just seeing the space that is being taken up by the frame you're packing below the widget. Believe me, there's nothing wrong or unexplainable about Tkinter -- when used right there is never any extra space that you can't account for, and it always grows and shrinks properly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25111/discussion-between-vreality-and-bryan-oakley)